# Unexpected result of property `copy` attribute

Tags: objective-c, properties, copy, nscopying

I've implemented NSCopying for own class and when I use this class as a property with **copy** attribute I'm expecting that it should use **[... copy]**/**[... copyWithZone:]** method. But it returns a reference to the same object. 
But if I use **copy** attribute for **NSString** it works or when I directly call **copy** method.
My question why **copy** attribute is not working for own class that supports NSCopying protocol?

```
@interface A: NSObject<NSCopying>
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *num;
@end

@implementation A

- (instancetype) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _num = @0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    A *newA = [A new];
    newA.num = [self.num copyWithZone:zone];
    return newA;
}

@end

@interface B: NSObject
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *str;
@property(nonatomic, copy) A *objA;
@end

@implementation B

- (instancetype) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _objA = [A new];
        _str = @"0";
    }
    return self;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        B *objB = [B new];

        A *newA1 = objB.objA.copy;
        newA1.num = @1;
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", newA1.num, objB.objA.num);

        A *newA = objB.objA;
        NSString *newStr = objB.str;

        newA.num = @1;
        newStr = @"1";

        NSLog(@"%@ %@", newA.num, objB.objA.num);
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", newStr, objB.str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0
1 1
1 0
```

Expected output:

```
1 0
1 0
1 0
```

Comment: Why do you expect `1 0` on the 2nd log? Note that `newA.num` is the same `NSNumber` instance as `objB.objA.num` so your actual output is what I would expect. The `copy` on the `objA` property is never called because you never actually assign anything to the `objA` property.

Comment: @rmaddy OK, thank you. I've understood the problem. I thought that property(copy) works as a getter.